# Using a scope variable to index a scope array in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I have a tree like structure, received as JSON from some PHP code which I wrote for my server.

The code is far to complex to post, so let's use an example:

A company has

- multiple departments, each of which has 0..n

  - jobs, each of which has 0..n

    - people

So, I can find myself with something like

```
$scope.departments[1].jobs[1].people[1]
$scope.departments[1].jobs[1].people[2]
```

etc

I have `$scope` variable for the current user-selected department, job and person.

My problem is where I want to use an `ng-repeat` of the jobs in the HTML view for the jobs.

The statement

```
<div ng-repeat="job in departments[{{departmentId}}].jobs>
```

gives `Error: [$parse:syntax]`, as does

```
<div ng-repeat="job in departments[$scope.departmentId].jobs>
```

(which I tried in desperation).

What is the correct syntax?

I am wondering if I will need to try

```
<div ng-repeat="job in GetJobsForCurrentDepartment()>
```

since `$scope.departmentId` would be in scope in my controller, but is not in the HTML view for the departments.

Comment: you could make your last option workable, by passing  `departmentId` in `GetJobsForCurrentDepartment` function like `<div ng-repeat="job in GetJobsForCurrentDepartment(departmentId)>  `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a view has a controller associated with it, and controller has a `$scope` associated with it. It is not required to use `$scope` the html element for referencing the variables defined in the controller. Any variable used with a element in a view is looked up in the scope associated with that element. `$scope` is required only in the script.

Thus you can write

```
<div ng-repeat="job in departments[departmentId].jobs>
```

This will fetch the value of departmentId & jobs inside it will be processed by the `ng-repeat` directive.

Comment: How does `departmentId ` get resolved, if I don't make it `{{departmentId}}`?  I will try it and get back to you

Comment: Expression syntax {{ }} is only required when 1] You want to bind its value to an element. 2] When you want to perform logical operation like
<span>
  1+2={{1+2}}
</span>
. In your case it is not required since ng-repeat is already a directive.

Comment: @Mawg Please accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Of course I will (+1). Sorry, a family emergency meant that I could not try it at home. I am now in the office and -  while test are running - putting together a fiddle to test it, which I will then link to in order to help future viewers of this question. Please bare with me :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to mention `$scope` attached with a varable in view

try like this

```
<div ng-repeat="job in departments[departmentId].jobs>
```

JS

```
$scope.departmentId=1;
```